#  C++ illegal operation on bound member function

Tags: c++, access-violation

I had a problem with an illegal access error and I have removed the default constructor from Player.h as I deduced that the problem was due to it. The problem I am having now is that the Level.cpp wanted a default constructor so I edited the Level.h file as shown. That problem was resolved but now I am not being able to return a pointer to the player. The error 'illegal operation on bound member function' is being shown. Any ideas please? I'm a beginner in C++ and any help would be appreciated.

Player.h:

```
#ifndef _TAG_PLAYER
#define _TAG_PLAYER
#pragma once
#include "Tile.h"
#include "Point.h"

class CGame;
class CPlayer : public CTile
{

public:

CPlayer(Point pos, CGame* game);
~CPlayer();
char getDisplay() ;
virtual bool canMove(const Direction direction, Point p) ;
virtual void move(const Direction direction, Point p);
bool CheckForHome() ;
};
 #endif _TAG_PLAYER
```

Player.cpp:

```
#include "Box.h"
#include "Level.h"
#include "Tile.h"


CPlayer::CPlayer(Point pos, CGame* game)
{
this->game=game;
Point p;
p.x=0;
p.y=0;
setPosition(p);
}


CPlayer::~CPlayer()
{
}

bool CPlayer::CheckForHome() {

Point p = getPosition();
bool OnHomeTile;

if(game->getLevel()->getTiles()[p.y][ p.x] == GOAL)
{
    OnHomeTile = true;
} else {
    OnHomeTile = false;
}

return OnHomeTile;
}


char CPlayer::getDisplay()
{
if (CheckForHome())
{
    return SOKOBANONGOAL_CHAR;
}
else
{
    return PLAYER_CHAR;
}
}
```

Level.h:

```
 #pragma once
 #include "Point.h"
 #include "Tile.h"
 #include "Player.h"
 #include "Box.h"
 #include <list>
 #include <string>

 class CGame;

 class CLevel 
   {
    private:


list<CBox> boxes;
TileType tiles[GRID_HEIGHT][GRID_WIDTH];
CPlayer player(Point p, CGame* game);  -> new declaration
//CPlayer player;                      -> old declaration

 protected:
CGame* game;

 public:
CLevel();
~CLevel();

CPlayer* getPlayer();
list<CBox>* getBoxes();
TileType (*getTiles())[GRID_WIDTH];

};
```

Constructor of Level.cpp

```
  CLevel::CLevel()
  {
this->game=game;
Point p;
p.x=0;
p.y=0;
player(p,game);

memset(tiles, GROUND, sizeof(TileType)*GRID_HEIGHT*GRID_WIDTH);
}
```

The function with the error in Level.cpp:

```
CPlayer* CLevel::getPlayer()
{
return &player;
}
```

Comment: When a `Player` is created, it is passed a pointer to a `CGame`. Do we know that this pointer is always valid?

Comment: The parameterless constructor `CPlayer()` looks bogus. If you ever call that then `game` will not be assigned.

Comment: Hmm I think my problem is that I cannot call CPlayer* player because there are 2 constructors. I have to use the other constructor CPlayer::CPlayer(Point pos, CGame* game) for it to work. I don't know if I'm reasoning it right though.

Comment: When I try removing the default constructor, I get an error in the constructor for CLevel. The error says that there is no default constructor. I'll edit the question to show you the constructor for CLevel

Answer (score 0):

Currently you've declared `player` as a member function not a member variable, which is why you're getting the weird error message. You can't mix the declaration and the initialisation of member variables like this.

You declaration should just be

```
CPlayer player;
```

But your CLevel constructor needs to initialise it, for example like:

```
CLevel() : player(Point(0, 0), game) { }
```

The problem with that though is that currently `CLevel` doesn't have a `game` to initialise the player with. Perhaps you could pass the `game` to the constructor of `CLevel`?

I think you need to read up on constructors and initialisation of members a bit more.